# "! Undefined control sequence." errors with table

Tags: tables, errors

I want to insert a table into my document with latex:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{}
    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
    \hline
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{S\&P500}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{GS10}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{TWEXMMTH}} \bigstrut\\
\cline{2-7}    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{p-value}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Yes/No}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{p-value}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Yes/No}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{p-value}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Yes/No}} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \hline
    \textbf{PFANDB} & 0,000 & Yes   & 0,193 & No    & 0,487 & No \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{PRAWM} & 0,001 & Yes   & 0,287 & No    & 0,601 & No \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{PNRG} & 0,001 & Yes   & 0,002 & Yes   & 0,543 & No \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{PMETA} & 0,014 & Yes   & 0,052 & No    & 0,537 & No \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \textbf{GOLD} & 0,359 & No    & 0,709 & No    & 0,166 & No \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

but it returns all the time the errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@sharp ->\multirow
{}
l.58 \multicolumn{1}{r}{\multirow{}}
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{S\&P5...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
LaTeX Font Info: Font shape `T1/ppl/bx/n' in size <10.95> not available
(Font) Font shape `T1/ppl/b/n' tried instead on input line 58.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.58 ...icolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{TWEXMMTH}} \bigstrut
\\
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.59 ...column{1}{c}{\textbf{Contagion}} \bigstrut
\\
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.62 ...s & 0,193 & No & 0,487 & No \bigstrut
\\
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.64 ...s & 0,287 & No & 0,601 & No \bigstrut
\\
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.66 ...s & 0,002 & Yes & 0,543 & No \bigstrut
\\
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.68 ...s & 0,052 & No & 0,537 & No \bigstrut
\\
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.70 ... & 0,709 & No & 0,166 & No \bigstrut
\\
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined....
```

I don't really understand. Can someone explain to me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `\multirow` is not a standard command you need to define it.  For example `\usepackage{multirow}` similarly `\bigstrut` needs to be defined.

Comment: however if you define `\multrow` as in the `multirow` package it needs values to know how many rows to span so your use here `\multirow{}` will give further errors. The best thing to do is simply delete all the `\multirow` and `\bigstrut` commands to get an error free table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't need `multirow`, and the code would be simpler without having tp repeat endlessly `\bigstrut`: the `makecell` package defines a `\makegapedcells` which adds some custom padding at the top and bottom of cells. Additionally, the `caption` package yields a more sensible spacing between captions and tables, when  captions are above tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
  \caption{}
    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
    \hline
    \hline%
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{S\&P500}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{GS10}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{TWEXMMTH}} \\
\cline{2-7} \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{p-value}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Yes/No}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{p-value}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Yes/No}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{p-value}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Yes/No}} \\
    \hline
    \hline
    \textbf{PFANDB} & 0,000 & Yes & 0,193 & No & 0,487 & No \\
    \hline
    \textbf{PRAWM} & 0,001 & Yes & 0,287 & No & 0,601 & No \\
    \hline
    \textbf{PNRG} & 0,001 & Yes & 0,002 & Yes & 0,543 & No \\
    \hline
    \textbf{PMETA} & 0,014 & Yes & 0,052 & No & 0,537 & No \\
    \hline
    \textbf{GOLD} & 0,359 & No & 0,709 & No & 0,166 & No \\
    \hline
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to have been helpful!